# The first use of Android emulator

Tags: android, c++, qt, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

By *Qt Creator 5.8*, and using `AVD_for_Nexus_4_by_Google API 22 armeabi` kit, I created an app named `App1` following the [Creating the Project](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/qtcreator-accelbubble-example.html) section.
Then created an `AVD` like the following the ran the app and chose that *AVD > OK* and waited and waited.

[image]

No virtual device will be shown to see my app work there and got the followings in the "Compile Output":

// ...(Many lines here ended to build successful)

*BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 5.413 secs

Android package built successfully in 14.136 ms.

-- File: C:/Users/CS/Documents/Qt/App1/build-App1-  Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_8_0-Debug/android-  build//build/outputs/apk/android-build-debug.apk

Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths:   QtQuick.Extras.Private.CppUtils

Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths:   QtQuick.Extras.Private.CppUtils

12:26:30: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.8.0\5.8\android_armv7\bin\androiddeployqt.exe" exited normally.

Error while building/deploying project App1 (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.8.0))

When executing step "Deploy to Android device"

12:28:35: Elapsed time: 02:20.*

What is your idea about the problem please? And is there any way to solve it please?

Answer (score 1):

To find out what happens here, you should at least turn on the verbose output for the deployment step (Build Settings -> Advanced Actions in Qt creator).

I saw this happening some times because the connection to android emulator was too slow to finish the deployment in time, and then switched to using real devices which work much better. Using the emulator did work for me when starting the emulator multiple times. Using the x86 version of the emulator and of Qt for developing only might make everything run much faster and smoother because the emulation has much better performance. In this case however you would not see arm-specific issues of your code and you would have to make sure your code works independent from the used processor architecture.

Be aware that there is [QTBUG-44697](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-44697) which might make an up-to-date Android Emulator from Google unusable for you. Reverting the [workaround](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/61798/1) which was introduced to make Qt work with earlier versions of the emulator made the emulator usable for me at least with Qt 5.6.2. This however requires to build Qt itself from (patched) sources.

Comment: First thank you for the answer. And I searched for **Build Settings** in *Qt Creator* and couldn't find it! :(

Comment: And I've been told that in 90 percent of the cases, Android apps are created using Arm (not x86)! So what is the difference between them? If x86 gives better output why shouldn't I use it so?

Comment: On the left click Projects, then under "Build and Run" select your Kit (probably android for armeabi-v7a...) and "Build". Then under Build settings you have the "Build steps". "Build Android SDK" contains the setting I am referring to.

Comment: Most android devices have arm processors, and you have to choose the architecture for the target CPU when using Qt, since it is based on the NDK, i.e. native code. So to run your code on an arm device (most devices are arm devices) you have to compile for arm. Using the x86 builds for debugging-on-the-emulator *only* can be helpful because the x86 emulation works so much (more than 10 times in my personal feeling) faster than the arm emulation when using the google android emulators.

Comment: OK. I found and turned on *verbose output*. There are many lines before *BUILD SUCCESSFUL*. I think they are not needed.But the below part with a project named **QApp_1** an *AVD* like above, I got the following messages:

Comment: **Total time: 6.244 secs
Stopped 0 compiler daemon(s).
Android package built successfully in 20.954 ms.
  -- File: C:/Users/CS/Documents/Qt/QApp_1/build-QApp_1-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_8_0-Debug/android-build//build/outputs/apk/android-build-debug.apk
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Extras.Private.CppUtils
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Extras.Private.CppUtils**

Comment: **01:36:09: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.8.0\5.8\android_armv7\bin\androiddeployqt.exe" exited normally.
01:36:09: Could not start process "" 
Error while building/deploying project QApp_1 (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.8.0))
When executing step "Custom Process Step"
01:36:09: Elapsed time: 00:23.**

Comment: OK, I got about the Arm and x86, thank you. Do you suggest me to first use x86 and run it using Android emulator. And then re-run it using Arm for publishing the app?

Comment: I would suggest to either debug with x86 emulator, or to debug with a real device that uses the target processor. The real device is probably the easiest thing to do - I suggested x86 because this question is about how to use the emulator.

Comment: The error then more looks like an issuewith your toolchain/debugger/sdk/ndk setup. Do you have platform tools installed in the sdk?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136343/discussion-between-franky-and-fourtytwo).